# An array with integers (seconds) and setTimeout()

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
times.forEach(function(element) {
    setTimeout(function() { alert(element); }, element * 1000); 
});
```

and this array: `[1, 5, 1]`

I expected an alert, first after 1 second, then another one after 5 seconds after the first, and the last one after 1 seconds after the second one, but the alert related to 1's are shown together at the beginning ...Any help?

Comment: Please stop constantly changing the code in your question. `5000` → `element * 1000`, then `[1,2,3]` → `[1,3,5]` have nothing to do with your textual description any more. What is the actual code that you used to produce the problem you're having?

Comment: @Bergi Sorry.. now it is the definetely code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reduce to achieve what you want this way:

```js
    [1, 5, 1].reduce(function(p, c, i) {
       setTimeout(function() {
          document.write(`element: ${c} <br>`);
       }, (p + c) * 1000);
       return p + c;
    }, 0);
```

Comment: This works, and is a creative use of reduce, but actually does not really solve the problem in terms of the OP not understanding how the javascript event stacks works. However, I revoked my -1 since it actually "fixes" the problem, which is what unfortunately the only thing most people care about on SO.

Answer (score 1):

You have to keep one very important thing in mind: The execution of javascript is asynchronous. The setTimeout in your example with alerts leads to the confusion. I guess you expect the following:

1s timeout
alert 1
1s timeout
alert 2
1s timeout
alert 3

However, what happens in reality is the following:

1s timeout started, 2s timeout started, 3s timeout started

alert 1 <- this takes some time to display, you have to click the "ok"

?s timeout, depending on how long it took you to react to alert 1

alert 2 <- possibly right after alert1

?s timeout

alert3 <- this might even occur *before* alert2 if the events are "stacked up"

To check, if your code works, don't use an alert, but rather something, that does not interfere like a `console.log()`.

```js
times = [1,2,3];

times.forEach(function(element) {
    setTimeout(function() { document.write(element); }, element * 1000); 
});
```

If you want to have the guaranteed timeframe *after* you alerts, you either

1) trigger the next timeout after the alert was closed  - or, better -

2) use callbacks that are hooked to the "alert close" event.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit: the answer was originally meant for the array `[1, 2, 3]`, but it will work for arbitrary numeric values.**

---

Right now, you are starting every single timeout at virtually the same moment:

- Alert after 1 seconds from now,
- Alert after 2 seconds from now,
- Alert after 3 seconds from now.

"now" doesn't change meaningly. This will effectively yield 1 second differences between pops. To *chain* these timeouts, you might do something like the following.

You can either take previous values into consideration, but still start all timeouts at the same moment:

```
var chainDelay = 0;

times.forEach(function (element) {
    setTimeout(function () { alert(element); }, (element + chainDelay) * 1000);
    chainDelay += element;
});
```

... or you can make it so that a new timeout is only started when the previous has fired:

```
function timeoutHandle(array, index) {
    if (index < array.length) {
        alert(array[index]);
        setTimeout(timeoutHandle, array[index] * 1000, array, index);
    }
}

setTimeout(timeoutHandle, times[0] * 1000, times, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use lodash or some other things to have clean code:

```js
var times = [1, 3, 1];

times.forEach(function(item) {
  _.delay(function() {
    alert(new Date() + ' : ' +item);
  }, item*1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lodash/lodash/4.11.1/dist/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -4):

As You wanted (:

```js
function alertDelayed(text, delay) {
  setTimeout(function() { 
      alert(new Date() + text); 
  }, delay);  
}

var times = [1, '5', '1anything']; // array can be different, so parseInt will sanitize it insidoe of foreach.
var previousElement = 0;
times.forEach(function(element) {
    alertDelayed(element, previousElement*1000 + parseInt(element)*1000); // alert after element seconds after previous alert
    previousElement = parseInt(element);
});
```

Comment: Why are you calling `parseInt` on a number? What does this `previousElement` thingy do? Why did you move the `setTimeout` into an extra function?

Comment: what's wrong?! I made the code to work as You expect!

Comment: @Bergi user says: I want to alert after 1 sec, +5 sec after of 1st alert and so on, it's not sequence of 1,2,3, it's random array! and also, I'm doing parseInt because I don't know what type of array it can be